# Obtener una relacion de otra relación, jquery, laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

estoy obteniendo un "grupo de lugares", tengo la clase

`LocationGroupPlace` la cual pertenece a la clase `Place`

**LocationGroupPlace.php:**

```
public function place()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Place::class);
}
```

La clase Place está relacionada con `medias` a través de su clase y de la clase `Location`

**Place.php:**

```
public function medias()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Media', 'App\Location',
        'place_id',
        'mediable_id',
        'id',
        'id'
    );
}
```

Actualmente estoy obteniendo las `medias` correctamente cuando se trata de un solo `Place`. Por ejemplo

```
  $medias = $this->placeRepository->getPlace($placeId)
      ->medias()
      ->whereIn('category', $categories)
      ->paginate($pageSize, ['*'], 'medias', $page);
```

Quiero hace lo mismo con LocationGroup (un grupo de places, o sea varios places), por el momento obtengo el grupo con su respectiva relación a cada uno de los `place`

**controlador:**

```
$placesGroup = $this->groupRepository->getGroupPlace($locationGroupIds, $categories, $pageSize, $page);
```

**repositorio:**

```
public function getGroupPlace($locationGroupIds, $categories, $pageSize, $page)
{
    $locationGroupPlace = LocationGroupPlace::wherein('place_id', $locationGroupIds)->with('place')->get();
    return $locationGroupPlace;
}
```

Hasta aquí, obtengo el grupo de places, con su respectiva relación `place`, pero desde aquí no puedo hacer contacto con `medias` para continuar con la consulta, mi clase `LocationGroupPlace` no tiene ninguna relación de manera directa con `medias` si no es pasando por la clase `Place`

cómo puedo obtener `medias` directamente como cuando lo hago con un solo place?

**Nota:** lo que quiero es evitar tener que hacer un foreach para obtenerlas una por una con la clase `Place` (que ya me está funcionando) porque de esa manera estaría duplicanto, triplicando o quintuplicando la consulta, además que $pageSize es el límite que debo mostrar

Answer (score 0):

**Solución:**

tuve que añadir la función `medias` a la clase **LocationGroupPlace.php** especificando `place_id` en `localKey` (el penúltimo `place_id` del código)

```
public function medias()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Media', 'App\Location',
        'place_id',
        'mediable_id',
        'place_id',   //localKey (eliminar este comentario)
        'id'
    );
}
```

y simplemente para acceder entonces añadimos "with" :)

```
public function getGroupPlace($locationGroupIds, $categories, $pageSize, $page)
{
    return LocationGroupPlace::wherein('place_id', $locationGroupIds)
             ->with('place')
             ->with('medias')->get();
}
```